# Is there a framework or library and a web service to get the atomic clock time at millisecond precision over NTP?

Tags: iphone, ios, datetime, time, ntp

I figured that the time on iOS is off by several seconds between devices even if automatic time settings are enabled.

So a developer recommended to use [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) to retrieve accurate time from atomic clock server. According to Wikipedia the Network Time Protocol has clever algorithms to eliminate network latency from the retrieval of time and can be precise to the millisecond. It seems iOS does not use this accuracy.

But has anyone ever done this on iOS already where time needs to be known to millisecond precision relative to atomic clock?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Date and Time from Apple Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075303/get-date-and-time-from-apple-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have never had a need to impliment NTP server connection in any app that wrote but I came across of a sample project quiet sometime ago that helped me do it for the purpose of learning how to do it. The project maybe. A bit older but I'm possitive you get the idea from it and can write the work around for yourself. Anyway here is the link to to project: https://github.com/jbenet/ios-ntp

Although it is licensed as MIT and you may need to get a license from the developer or better yet just write your own. Hope this helps you out man.

Comment: @openfrog, I haven't encountered those issues...it seems to work quite nicely for me.