# set today's date in UIDatePicker not device date

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

While showing date picker I'm using this code to show today's date

```
[_datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
```

If I change the device date to some other date the date picker's date is also changing... But I need to show today's date... How to do this

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want to do is to [get the date from an authoritative source, like a NTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075303/get-date-and-time-from-apple-server).

Some places where you can find open source include ["ios-ntp"](https://github.com/jbenet/ios-ntp) or ["NHNetworkTime"](https://github.com/huynguyencong/NHNetworkTime), the latter of which (once building within your project) is as simple as doing "`NSDate *networkDate = [NSDate networkDate];`".

And once you have that date, that's the `NSDate` object you pass into your `_datePicker`.

Answer (score 1):

Today's date is always `[NSDate date]`. If you change device date, device doesn't know anything else.
You can try http://www.ntp.org to get `Internet Time` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the current Date/Time from the backend server and set it to the Date Picker.